# How to append a loop value to a list?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I don't fathom why the output isn't a list...am I appending wrongly?

```
from numpy import *

b=0.1;g=0.5;l=632.8;p=2;I1=[I];I=0

for a in arange(-0.2,0.2,0.001):

    I+=b**2*(sin(pi/l*b*sin(a)))**2/(pi/l*b*sin(a))**2*(sin(p*pi /l*g*sin(a)))**2/(sin(pi/l*g*sin(a)))**2

I1.append(I)  

print (I)

output: 15.999998678557855
```

Comment: The second line already doesn't work. Also, you are printing `I` which is a number. Did you mean to print `I1`?

Comment: `b=0.1;g=0.5;l=632.8;p=2;I1=[I];I=0` is ugly. `b, g, l, p, I1, I = 0.1, 0.5, 632.8, 2, [I], 0` is ugly as well but better if you insist of stuffing all into a single line.

Comment: @nnnmmm why the second line doesn't work? Anyway you're right, I want to print I1! ahaha

Answer (score 0):

Several errors in your code, missing imports etc. See comments inside code for fixes:

```
from numpy import arange
from math import sin,pi

b = 0.1
g = 0.5
l = 632.8 
p = 2
I = 0          # you need to specify I 
I1 = [I]       # before you can add it

for a in arange(-0.2,0.2,0.001):

    I += b**2 * (sin(pi/l*b*sin(a)))**2 / (pi/l*b*sin(a))**2 * (sin(p*pi /l*g*sin(a)))**2 / (sin(pi/l*g*sin(a)))**2

    I1.append(I)  # by indenting this you move it _inside_ the loop 

print (I)
print (I1)
```

Output:

```
15.999998678557855
[0, 0.03999999014218294, 0.07999998038139602, 0.1199999707171788, ....] # shortened
```